# API Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:389 Apollo-React MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, webpack, graphql, react-apollo

I am trying to run a API service with Apollo(GraphQL), React, Webpack and MongoDB on Windows environment . The service starts success, but when I send the first request the service crashed.

I'm using this versions:

- npm v5.6.0
- node v8.9.4
- webpack v3.8.1
- webpack-dev-server v3.0.0
- apollo-server v^0.3.3
- apollo-upload-server v^4.0.0-alpha.3
- mongodb v^2.2.33

This is the output when the service starts:

```
C:\test-dev3\name_app\api>npm run start

Webpack is watching the files…

Hash: fec0c0aa558d4a8b3bf7
Version: webpack 3.10.0
Time: 2388ms
           Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
server.bundle.js  94.3 kB       0  [emitted]  server
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/log-apply-result.js] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.31 kB {0} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js] (webpack)/hot/log.js 1.04 kB {0} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot/poll.js?1000] (webpack)/hot/poll.js?1000 1.16 kB {0} [built]
[./src/carouselItem/schema.js] ./src/carouselItem/schema.js 4.96 kB {0} [built]
[./src/connectors/mongodb.js] ./src/connectors/mongodb.js 2.06 kB {0} [built]
[./src/context.js] ./src/context.js 706 bytes {0} [built]
[./src/index.js] ./src/index.js 451 bytes {0} [built]
[./src/options.js] ./src/options.js 786 bytes {0} [built]
[./src/schema.js] ./src/schema.js 975 bytes {0} [built]
[./src/server.js] ./src/server.js 3.45 kB {0} [built]
[./src/site/models.js] ./src/site/models.js 624 bytes {0} [built]
[./src/site/schema.js] ./src/site/schema.js 1.65 kB {0} [built]
[./src/user/models.js] ./src/user/models.js 2.81 kB {0} [built]
[./src/user/schema.js] ./src/user/schema.js 1.64 kB {0} [built]
   [0] multi webpack/hot/poll?1000 ./src/index.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
    + 33 hidden modules
Options file loaded
Connected to mongoDB [object Object]
GraphQL-server listening on port 3000.
```

When the service crashes:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:389
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)
```

The package.json:

```
{
  "name": "name_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "API to expose",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --config webpack/config/dev.config.js",
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "keywords": [
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "bugs": {
    "url": ""
  },
  "homepage": "",
  "eslintIgnore": [
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "**/dist/**"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1",
    "eslint": "^4.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^21.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "start-server-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.6",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "^0.3.3",
    "apollo-upload-server": "^4.0.0-alpha.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "graphql": "^0.11.7",
    "graphql-tools": "^2.6.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.1",
    "ldapjs": "^1.0.2",
    "lowdb": "^1.0.0",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "mongoose": "^4.12.4",
    "promise-ftp": "^1.3.4",
    "promises-all": "^1.0.0",
    "ramda": "^0.25.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8"
  }
}
```

Webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const StartServerPlugin = require('start-server-webpack-plugin');
const SERVER_ENTRY_NAME = 'server';
const BUILD_FOLDER = 'dist';
const OUTPUT_SUFFIX = '.bundle.js';
const WEBPACK_HOT_POLL = 'webpack/hot/poll?1000';

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    [SERVER_ENTRY_NAME]: [
      WEBPACK_HOT_POLL,
      path.resolve(__dirname, '../../src/index.js'),
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(BUILD_FOLDER),
    filename: `[name]${OUTPUT_SUFFIX}`,
  },
  watch: true,
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    __filename: true,
    __dirname: true,
  },
  externals: [
    nodeExternals({
      whitelist: [WEBPACK_HOT_POLL],
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new StartServerPlugin(SERVER_ENTRY_NAME + OUTPUT_SUFFIX),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        BUILD_TARGET: JSON.stringify('server'),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: Port 389 is usually used by an LDAP server. Is your service configured to go to an LDAP server for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this address is in use: 127.0.0.1:389, change the port.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure MongoDB server is started on windows environment by opening `cmd` with Administrator privilege and start MongoDb server by writing

`net start MongoDB`